# Forcelink classes using intel moe (java to ios)?

Tags: java, ios, binding, libgdx

How can I force link classes using intel moe with a libgdx project.

Using roboVM I could easily add this to robovm.xml

```
<forceLinkClasses>
   <pattern>com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*</pattern>
</forceLinkClasses>
```

How can I do the same using intel moe? I am using json to create classes via reflection so this is a necessity.

Thanks

Comment: What does forcelink stands for? Wrapping the iOS frameworks to Java?

Comment: I believe that it enables the Java classes to be available in iOS at runtime as opposed to just being available at compile time, useful for static libraries etc.

Comment: I don't think that is possible in MOE, but if I were you I would ask the question on their [site](https://discuss.multi-os-engine.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else in the future, I had to create the file `proguard.append.cfg`, which allows you to define java packages which must be kept in the build; an example:

```
-keep class com.mypackage.** { *; }
```